# Rails isn't preserving URL parameters after validation fails when the action "new" is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, url-parameters

When I'm creating a product with this URL 
http://localhost:3000/versions/new?product_id=1
and the validations fails, Rails isn't keeping the product_id in the URL

And I get this URL
http://localhost:3000/versions

I need that parameter to keep the filter by product and for the links like "back", but I don't want to use "session" or "redirect" to do that.

I don't understand why Rails doesn't keep the URL. I have used CakePHP before with forms, parameters and validations like that and I'm sure that I didn't face that problem.

```
def create
    @version = Version.new(version_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @version.save
            format.html { redirect_to @version, notice: I18n.t('controllers.versions.created_successfully', default: 'Version was successfully created.') }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @version }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @version.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. to make it easier for us to help you, can you please edit your question and add the relevant section of your log-file (watch the server window when you click the submit button on the form and copy just the bit that happens after you click the button). Also the method called `version_params` ? thanks

Comment: I'll add to the above request the following: 1) The line(s) in config/routes.rb that refer to this controller 2) the output of: bundle exec rake routes | grep version (assuming the above controller has version in its name.)

Comment: I got my answer here on Stack Overflow. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first explain why this is happening

The form posts to `versions_path` which is `/versions`, when the validation fails, rails (by default) doesn't redirect back, instead it renders inside the same path, which is `/versions` like you said, you can find out more about CRUD routes from [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

In your case i think it's more suitable to [create a nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), so the url would be more like this `/products/1/versions/new`, 
in the routes file it would look like this

```
resources :products
  resources :versions
end
```

This way when the validation fails, you'll get redirected to the `product_versions_path` which will map to `/products/1/versions`, you'll still have access to the product id `1` in a variable called `params[:product_id]`.

Comment: You are right! I didn't know about that because I'm new on Rails. I think that is a little different in CakePHP. Thank you very much.